# How do I get a folder name from a file path without VBA

Tags: excel

I have a long list of file paths and I include the containing folder of each file/folder. I need to go from

```
c:\Top\Middle\Bottom\file1.jpg
c:\Top\Middle\file2.jpg
```

to

```
c:\Top\Middle\Bottom
c:\Top\Middle
```

There can be folders that are deeply nested and file names vary in length.

How can it be done with a formula (MID, RIGHT, LEFT, SUBSTITUTE, FIND, etc.) without VBA code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a beast of a nested formula, but it actually does work.

```
LEFT(A1,SEARCH("\@\",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","\@\",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","")))))
```

*Based on a formula found at http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/VBA/5563.html*

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula:

```
  =LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-MATCH("\",MID(A1,LEN(A1)-ROW(1:255),1),0)-1)
```

It must be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination.